# Converting a sentence with "perceived" into an active voice

Tags: passive-voice

I'm trying to avoid passive voice, so instead of writing "as perceived by a patient" I want to write:

> A symptom is any change, typical for disease, as a patient perceives it
>   and describes it.

Does anyone think this sounds terribly wrong or creepy..?

Comment: And why are you trying to avoid passive voice?  “*A **symptom** is any change, typical for a disease, as perceived or described by a patient.*”  is the idiomatic way these types of definitions are expressed.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid passive because, in general, I want to present people more as active beings rather than ones to whom things just happen. So, if "idiomatic" expression will be natural for a native speaker (which I'm not) and if I change this, a native speaker could think I'm trying to change the language?

Comment: What is the context here? A journal article? A patient brochure? A textbook?

Comment: This one is just a part of a definition intended for a medical dictionary.

Comment: Unless one of the claims to fame of this dictionary is “all definitions written in active voice!” (Or rather: “We wrote all our definitions in active voice!’)  I’d stick to passive.

Comment: OK, I appreciate.

Comment: Either way, unfortunately, whether a sentence sounds creepy or wrong is primarily opinion-based and off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that unspecific symptoms can be used neither in an actively voiced sentence nor in an actively voiced *definition*.

For example:

> The symptoms caused her death.

We would not say that. (We would say, "The disease caused her death.")

However:

> The swelling of her brain (a symptom of her aneurysm) caused her death.

That sentence is fine. It's in the active voice, and the subject is a named symptom.

Similarly:

> The rash grew in size.

Again, it's a named symptom that's the subject of an action.

But what you're talking about is a *definition*—and not just of a particular symptom, but of the word *symptom* itself.

A standard medical definition (I'm not looking it up in a dictionary) could be *any observable phenomenon caused by an illness or disorder*. But by its very nature, when used in a definition, a *symptom* is an object, not a verbal subject.

Although I would be fascinated to be proven wrong, I can't think of a definition of *any* word that actually uses an active voice. Mainly because the word has not yet been defined in such a way that it can be used as the subject of an active voice construction.

---

So far, I've been discussing *definitions*. That's because your example sentences stars with "[A] symptom is any change . . ." That's a defining term.

But let's say you don't actually care about what a symptom is, and you only want to refer to a patient's awareness of a symptom. (You say, "I want to present people more as active beings rather than ones to whom things just happen.")

The problem with your example sentence (in addition to the confusion over it being a definition) is that it's not actually in the active voice *either*.

A possible rephrasing to put it in the active voice:

> Patients may perceive and describe symptoms of disease.

If that's what you were looking for, that's the kind of rephrasing I would suggest.

Comment: Here are 2 definitions I've found in the titles of 2 PubMed articles  1.  "Adherence to drug treatment in association with how the patient perceives care and information on drugs." ([here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17181676)) 2. "Pain is what the patient perceives as pain." ([here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12070850)) In my case from the question and in these 2 cases, it is always "patients perceives." It does not look wrong to me.

Comment: @jan I'm obviously not an expert on medical terminology or definitions.  But I will say that "X is what is perceived as X" would never be accepted in an English dictionary.  And this is a forum for discussing English. If you're fine with the use of "patient perceives" and your original definition as a term in this medical dictionary, then go with that.